# How to fix error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client' in python3?

Tags: python, http

The following is my code.

```
import http
h1 = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.bing.com')
```

I think it's ok.But python give me the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'.

I wanted to know why and how to fix it.Thanks.

Comment: works fine for me using Python 3.4...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, importing a package doesn't automatically import all of its submodules.*

So try this:

```
import http.client
```

---

If that doesn't work, then most likely you've got a file named `http.py`, or a directory named `http`, somewhere else on your `sys.path` (most likely the current directory). You can check that pretty easily:

```
import http
http.__file__
```

That should give some directory like `/usr/lib/python3.3/http/__init__.py` or `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/http/__init__.py` or something else that looks obviously system-y and stdlib-y; if you instead get `/home/me/src/myproject/http.py`, this is your problem. Fix it by renaming your module so it doesn't have the same name as a stdlib module you want to use.

---

If that's not the problem, then you may have a broken Python installation, or two Python installations that are confusing each other. The most common cause of this is that installing your second Python edited your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but your first Python is still the one that gets run when you just type `python`.

---

<sub>* But sometimes it does. It depends on the module. And sometimes you can't tell whether something is a package with non-module members (like `http`), or a module with submodules (`os`). Fortunately, it doesn't matter; it's always save to `import os.path` or `import http.client`, whether it's necessary or not.</sub>